# limit of a function at infinity is lower bounded

Tags: limits

Suppose for a function $f(x)$, we have $\underset{x \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}~ f(x) \geq L$ with $L$ a finite number. By mimicking the definition of limit at infinity, can we say the following:
For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $M$ such that, $f(x) > L - \epsilon$ for $x > M$?

Comment: Does $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ exist and is bigger than $L$ (including if it's infinite), or did you mean to say $\liminf_{x\to\infty}f(x)\geq L$?

Comment: @Arthur Good question. $L$ is a finite number, and at this point we are not sure whether  $\underset{x \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}~ f(x)$ exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Since, if $a\le b + \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon$ then $a\le b$